# How to remove random characters appearing in the VF email?

Tags: email-template, visualforce-template

When sending the VF email template we are getting  random characters appearing in the subject of the e-mail. Also i am getting  this random character in the body of the email for the empty email which is sent from salesforce. Please let me how remove this random character.
[image: In Subect of the email]

[image: In Body of the Email:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in your email-to-case setting, please refer to this knowledge base article:

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005080&language=en_US